# Tratamiento de Listas Encadenadas

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Necesito un método que admita como parámetro un valor que se va a insertar en la lista. El valor se insertará en orden después de todos los que sean menores y justo antes de los que sean mayores o iguales. La lista permanecerá ordenada de menor a mayor en todo momento.

Adjunto el código

```
import random

from slt import SortedLinkedList

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = SortedList()

    for i in range(10):
        my_list.insert(random.randint(10, 78))

    for item in my_list:
        print(item)
```

La primera parte, la superior, no puede ser modificada porque la empleo para otra cosa

```
class SortedLinkedList:
    class Node:
      def __init__(self, value, next_node = None):
          self.value = value
          self.next = next_node

     def __init__(self):
         self.first = None
         self.len = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len

    def __iter__(self):
        self.current = self.first
        return self

    def __next__(self):
       if self.current != None:
           result = self.current.value
           self.current = self.current.next_node
           return result
       else:
           raise StopIteration
```

Esta otra parte superior tampoco la puedo modificar porque voy a reutilizar el código en otro módulo

```
def add_value(self, value):
  # Este es el método que he intentado
    if value == 0:
        self.add_value(value)
    elif value == len(self):
        self.append(value)
    elif value < 0 or value > len(self):
        raise IndexError
    else:
        current = self.__first
        current_pos = 1

        while current_pos < value:
            current = current.next_node
            current_pos += 1

        current.next_node = self.Node(value, current.next_node)
        self.__len += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren dos maneras:

- Si lo que quieres es insertar en el índice de la lista adecuado:

```
def insert_element_sorted_in_list(list_to_append, element):
    if list_to_append[-1] < element:
        return list_to_append.append(element)
    else:
        index = next(k for k, value in enumerate(list_to_append) if value > element)
        return list_to_append.insert(index, element)


number_list = []
number = int(input("Inserta elemento lista - :"))
number_list.append(number)

for num in number_list:
    print(num)
while True:
    number = int(input("Inserta elemento lista - :"))
    insert_element_sorted_in_list(number_list, number)
    for num in number_list:
        print(num)
```

- Otra manera que no emplea el método insert:

```
def insert_list_element_and_sort(list_to_append, element):
    list_to_append.append(element)
    return list_to_append.sort()


number_list = []

while True:
    number = input("Inserta elemento lista - :")
    insert_list_element_and_sort(number_list, number)
    for num in number_list:
        print(num)
```

Espero que te sirva.